# Java: command not found for CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611

Tags: centos, java

I have installed java the same was as following steps on another similar CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 and its working fine. On this machine I ran the same steps as follow

```
1. wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz"
2. tar -xvzf jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz
3. alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/java 2
4. alternatives --config java
5. alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javac 2
6. alternatives --set javac /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javac
7. export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin
```

So each time when I ran this steps again then I the java -version works. After some times it becomes the same command not found.

What is my mistake?

Comment: what does `echo $PATH` show when you see a "command not found" message?

Comment: @thrig its showing /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Comment: @thrig when I run this echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin I notice the java -version is working back?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set that `PATH` modification in your shell configuration, e.g. `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` to make it stick around.

Comment: @thrig why is it ok on my other machine? Ok what command should I run to make sure it stick?

Comment: Looks like a typo in line 3 of your question. Missing the `/bin/` in the location of the installed java. Should be ` alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 2`. Remember to adjust the priority (in you case the `2`) if there are multiple versions of Java installed. I usually make the priority a string based on the release. So you case I would have used ` alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 180121`.

Comment: @Deathgrip ok is there any thing I must do? How about the .bashrc adjustment should I do that?

Comment: @user8012596 - Did you execute the correct command: `alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 180121`?

Comment: @Deathgrip yes I ran this alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 180121. So far I dont know it haven misbehave yet. Anything I must make sure its ok. Maybe you can add as answer so I can vote it.

Comment: Just `java -version` to ensure it's getting the proper java.

Comment: @Deathgrip yes I am getting it correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a typo in line 3 of your question. Left out the '/bin/' in '/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/java' in the alternatives command. Should have been '/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java'.

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 180121
```

Extra information:
When I install Java this way, I also make some of the ancillary programs slaves in the alternatives command. For the priority, I make a string from the Java release number. You can get by with just the single line command, but I would have used something similar to the following:

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java \
   /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 180121 \
   --slave /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jar \
   --slave /usr/bin/jarsigner jarsigner /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jarsigner \
   --slave /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javac \
   --slave /usr/bin/javadoc javadoc /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javadoc \
   --slave /usr/bin/javah javah /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javah \
   --slave /usr/bin/javap javap /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javap \
   --slave /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javaws \
   --slave /usr/bin/jconsole jconsole /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jconsole \
   --slave /usr/bin/jcontrol jcontrol /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jcontrol \
   --slave /usr/bin/jdb jdb /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jdb \
   --slave /usr/bin/jhat jhat /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jhat \
   --slave /usr/bin/jinfo jinfo /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jinfo \
   --slave /usr/bin/jmap jmap /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jmap \
   --slave /usr/bin/jps jps /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jps \
   --slave /usr/bin/jrunscript jrunscript /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jrunscript \
   --slave /usr/bin/jsadebugd jsadebugd /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jsadebugd \
   --slave /usr/bin/jstack jstack /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jstack \
   --slave /usr/bin/jstat jstat /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jstat \
   --slave /usr/bin/jstatd jstatd /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jstatd \
   --slave /usr/bin/jvisualvm jvisualvm /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jvisualvm
```

Comment: I dont get you When I install Java this way, I also make some of the ancillary programs slaves in the alternatives command. For the priority, I make a string from the Java release number. You can get by with just the single line command, but I would have used something similar to the following:?

Comment: It bundles all the Java commands. So if you wanted to remove the alternative, `alternatives --remove java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java` will remove all the links for the other 1.8.0_121 programs (javac, javadoc, etc).

Comment: normally I use is java and javac only. Do I need to include all then ?

Comment: I notice you use this 180121 the bigger number is better or smaller?

Comment: A higher priority will be the one in use automatically. You can manually override, but if I need a specific version I use the fully qualified paths to where I unpacked the tarball. I create the priority from the Java release. 1.8.0_121 becomes 180121. When I install the next update (8u131 for example), the priority will be 180131. Since it's higher, it becomes the default version.

Comment: At my job we use a lot of the jcontrol, jconsole, jmap, and other utility programs. Which is why I wrote a little script to include them all.

Comment: but is the way or method I am installing java for centos is it correct right?

Comment: It's fine. Seems like you really only use java and javac. It's one of those "whatever works for you" things. At home on my Ubuntu box, I only set up the java alternative. That's why I edited my answer and put the one liner at the top. You're good with just fixing `alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 180121`.

Comment: ok so you are ubuntu user which you suggest for server base centos or ubuntu?

Comment: No real preference as a server platform. For a home desktop, Ubuntu. At the day job we are about 50/50.

Comment: 50/50 is what centos ?

Comment: Of the 6 or 7 hundred Linux VMs we run, about 50/50 CentOS/Ubuntu. Handful of licensed RHEL, a couple FreeBSD, and a handful of Solaris x86.

Comment: just wondering all these vm and cloud are they stable compare to actual server?

Comment: Moderators are going to get annoyed. "Comments are not for conversations". Go to chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60443/discussion-between-user8012596-and-deathgrip).

Comment: Sent you an invite to a room I created.